# Add an additional item to cart if checkbox=checked, AFTER clicking certain CTA

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a function which adds Gift wrapping service to cart, IF a checkbox is checked when clicking an existing CTA button.
So basically;
IF CTA is clicked while checkbox is checked, add another item(SKU) to cart, which is the gift wrapping service.

I have this jQuery, but I can't figure out what to write inside the function. Also, not sure if this is the correct way either, so I'm open to suggestions.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){ //use this to see if the checkbox is checked or not
         //do something...
     }
});
```

Let's say the CTA class is `.cta`, what code do I insert inside the above function? Or is there another approach for this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding a click event to the checkbox, when you actually want to trigger this when the CTA gets clicked? That is the wrong way around to begin with.

Comment: That's why I need help. Can't figure out the right approach :/  Do I change what comes before ".click(function)" to the CTA class instead? Or do I move the .click(function) to somewhere else? The idea was that there is a click function to the checkbox because when it's clicked it adds another item to the cart, which is gift wrapping service. But I thought it would be better to do it as follows= if CTA is clicked while checkbox is checked, gift wrapping item(SKU) is added to cart. Sorry if it's confusing, English isn't my first language.

Comment: You bind your own click handler to your CTA element, and then inside that you [`trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the click event on the checkbox element - that will make it execute the click handler for the checkbox then, same as if the user had clicked it themselves.

Comment: (If it actually _is_ a click handler on the checkbox in the first place - usually the `change` event should be used for that kind of thing, rather than click, so make sure that’s correct in the first place, otherwise you’ll be triggering the wrong event, and then nothing will happen. If you trigger the change event, then you might have to _set_ the checkbox to checked beforehand as well.)

Comment: I see, makes sense. But I'd like the checkbox to be unchecked as default. But, what if they check it, and then uncheck it? Is that why you said it's better to use the ```change``` event instead?
Also, do you have any idea how I go about writing that code? It sounds too complicated for me, as I'm not super experienced jQuery

Comment: Not sure what you actually want now, do you want to add gift wrapping _in any case_, when the user clicks your CTA, or _only_ if they checked the checkbox beforehand? (Then what is the CTA still needed for?)

Comment: Yes, still need the CTA, because this CTA is already there and has a function, it redirects the user to the checkout when clicked. Because when you click on "collect @ store" CTA, you will get this popup where you either choose to pay now, or later(which requires you to fill in your name etc...). But this function is only going to apply for users who choose to pay now. So this CTA will have 2 functions, the old one where it redirects to the checkout, and, if the new checkbox is checked, it will also add another item(which is gift wrapping), to the cart, and redirect at the same time.

Comment: I really can’t tell what exactly your situation is now, whether you have this part: _“because when it's clicked it adds another item to the cart, which is gift wrapping service”_ already implemented, or not.

Comment: Okay; there is an existing CTA button right. This CTA button is basically a "Go-to-cart" button. I want to add a checkbox above it, if this checkbox IS checked when the user clicks on the CTA button, it will add another item to the cart AND redirect the user to the cart.

Comment: That adding of another item to the cart will likely require a request to the server to begin with, probably via AJAX in the background (in which case you would have to “wait” until that AJAX request is finished somehow, otherwise your redirect to the cart would likely cancel it) - or you would have to send the necessary data _together_ with your “redirect” (by making that an actual form submit, that sends the necessary data directly to the cart page, so that the extra product will be added, and shown when the result page loads and displays the cart.) […]

Comment: […] But this all very much depends on the specifics of how your system works in the first place, and so far, you haven given close to none.